# Semantic-UI 2.0 in Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, flexbox, semantic-ui

according to Semantic UI's section on browser support (https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI#browser-support) Semantic-UI is compatible to IE9, using prefixes.

I now inspected my work with Semantic UI and saw that grid layouts make heavy use of flexbox CSS.
When I open my HTML prototype in IE9, the layout is messed up.

Can I make Semantic UI avoid using flex box layout?
Or is there a JS lib / polyfill available to get it work in IE9?

This is quite important for me, since I am developing for Enterprise customers, they are still depending on IE9...

Kind regards,
Sascha,

Comment: The document you linked says: "*Browser Support: IE10+. Flexbox components are not supported by IE9 and may not appear correctly.*"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, the document I linked, stated "IE 9 supported via CSS-prefixes" - just until I opened this question an issue in the GitHub project. It seems as if the section has quickly been corrected...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linked document indeed contained an outdated passage.
Since I also posed this question on the corresponding Github project, the developers meanwhile where able to update the passaging, now stating that only IE versions >= 10 are supported by Semantic UI.